# Using russian login in winrm

Tags: ansible

I try to connect to Windows Server with this host file using Ansible 2.10

[server]
1.1.1.1

[server:vars]
ansible_user="Администратор"
ansible_password=######
ansible_port=5985
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore

I've got error 
fatal: [1.1.1.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ntlm: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-12: ordinal not in range(128)", "unreachable": true}

Connection work if I will not use russian symbol in ansible_user. 
Has anyone know how to deal with such of issue ?

Ansible version is 2.10.7. 
Ansible installed on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi  Artem31 welcome to SO. According to a search for "ntlm ascii codec" that found what appears to be [your same issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/69828#issuecomment-644629447) in which they claim it is fixed by upgrading `ntlm-auth >= 1.5.0`; can you try that?

Comment: @mdaniel. Hello ! Many thanks for you. pip install ntlm-auth --upgrade helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what appears to be [that same issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/69828#issuecomment-644629447), they say it is fixed by upgrading `ntlm-auth >= 1.5.0`